# PHP form with recaptcha and mysql insert error

Tags: php, mysql, recaptcha

I'm  noob when it comes to PHP. I'm trying to learn and build a really nice php form that uses recaptcha and sends data to mysql. I'm having issues getting the mysql function to work. I get the error

> syntax error, unexpected ';' in testing.php on line 42

When I remove that it starts up with other errors. Any assistance with this error would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // keys from Google reCaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
    $sitekey = 'site_key';
    $secretkey = 'secret_key';

    $alert = '';
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $fullname;$username;$email;$message;$captcha;
            if(isset($_POST['fullname']))
                    $fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
            if(isset($_POST['username']))
                    $username=$_POST['username'];
            if(isset($_POST['email']))
                    $email=$_POST['email'];
            if(isset($_POST['message']))
                    $message=$_POST['message'];
            if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
                    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

                if(!$captcha)
                $alert = '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Please wait until the captcha protection give you a check mark.</div>';

            $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretkey.'&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

        if($response->success==false)
        {
            /* lets set the error message for the alert... */
            if ($alert=='')
                $alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Some how you have been detected has a spammer.</div>';
            }
        else
        {

            //Connecting to sql db.
            $connect = mysqli_connect("XXXX","XXXX","XXXX","XXXX");
            //Sending form data to sql db.
            mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO pro_tools.Users (full_name, users_name, email, message)
            VALUES ('$_POST[post_fullname]', '$_POST[post_username]', '$_POST[post_email]', '$_POST[post_message]')";
            $alert = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you for your submission!</div>';
            }
    }

?>
```

Comment: which is line number 42

Answer (score 1):

Line number 42 to 45 will be :-

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO pro_tools.Users (full_name, users_name, email, message)
VALUES (" . $_POST['post_fullname'] . "," . $_POST['post_username'] . "," . $_POST['post_email'] . "," . $_POST['post_message'] . ")");
$alert .= "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Thank you for your submission!</div>";
```

You have **syntax error** also you have to **[concat](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php)** variable to have proper html in **$alert**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a sytax error here

```
 $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretkey.'&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

I will try to fix it

```
 $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretkey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

You use this ' instead of this " you mixed it

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a bit off, missing a parenthesis at the end to close `mysqli_query`. However, you are vulnerable to SQL-injection and should therefor use prepared statements.

An example is given below

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO pro_tools.Users (full_name, users_name, email, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $_POST['fullname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'], );
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

This would replace your current code:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO pro_tools.Users (full_name, users_name, email, message)
        VALUES ('$_POST[post_fullname]', '$_POST[post_username]', '$_POST[post_email]', '$_POST[post_message]')";
```

You mention "other errors showing up", we don't know what those are - and if you require assistance with those, you have to tell us what errors appear, and on which lines they are on (we don't know what line 42 is in your code).

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error in your **INSERT** query generation:

Replace your **mysqli_query** with the following codes.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pro_tools.Users (full_name, users_name, email, message)"
                    . "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['post_fullname'], $_POST['post_username'], $_POST['post_email'], $_POST['post_message']);
            $stmt->execute();
```